# Input field like stackOverflow tags input field

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces with JSF. I need a input component that allows users to submit upto 5 tags in a single input field just like the tags input field on stackOverflow. There must be also a functionality to suggest the tags(as the user starts typing) as it is available here.

I couldnt figure out a way to do so using Primefaces components. What could be a better way to achieve that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input multiple with tags without autoCompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635358/input-multiple-with-tags-without-autocompletion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) plugin for your purpose.

Example for you :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myID").autocomplete('/Urlthatreturns/results', { multiple: true,
           multipleSeparator: "," }).result(function (event, item) {
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `autocomplete`, I guess, allows for just one input.. I want something similar to Stack overflow tags input field where you can specify multiple tags in a single field

Comment: No, you can use autocomplete for multiple things by using multiple property. I edited my post for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Primefaces [Multiple Selection AutoComplete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteMultiple.jsf). It will fit your needs.