# Is there an ASP.NET TextBox with e-mail auto-complete like Google Mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, gmail

Currently I'm looking for a way to either extend a standard `<asp:TextBox />` control or use a 3rd-party control (like e.g. DevExpress) to create an e-mail receiver text field like the one currently available in Google Mail:

[image: Google Mail] 
*(Screenshot in German, sorry)*

The text box allows for entering multiple e-mail addresses and auto-completes them very elegant from a backend database.

I would like to have the same feature as Google currently does. In my opinion the challenge would be to allow for multiple separate items that auto-complete independent of each other.

**So my question is:**

Are you aware of any examples/production-ready controls that fit into my ASP.NET C# 4.0 infrastructure for solving this task?

**Addition**

If I think longer about it, this seems to be *very* similar to the "Tags" field at the bottom of Stack Overflow when creating a new question. Is there source code available for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847836/input-field-like-stackoverflow-tags-input-field/6847887#6847887

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit AutocompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx) for this

Comment: Wow, that's it! I wasn't aware that you can have multiple words. Thanks a lot, @Stephan.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) for this kind of thing.