# Is there an equivalent to p:chips before Primefaces 6.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm writing a form where at some point the user can write several informations about the passengers of a car.

Example : passengers
I type the 1st name, then I want to click on enter to write the 2nd name and so on.

On the Primefaces website it seems that Chips is a good solution to my problem (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml) but it's only available on Primefaces 6.1 and I work on Primefaces 6.0  (I can't update it).

is there any other solution or alternative ?
Thanks !

Comment: No there isn't, you could add the chip component to the primefaces 6.0 source code and compile it by yourself. But why you can't update to PF 6.1? Maybe it would be better to solve this problem than invest time to make a workaround.

Comment: And the chips component does not have any 'autocomplete' as far as I know. With some small changes (search stackoverflow) you can make the autocomplete component into one...

Comment: I can't even get chips to work when I upgrade to PF 6.1. I get "<p:chips> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: chips"

Answer (score 1):

With some small changes to the existing  `p:autocomplete` you can make it behave like the chips component if I understand the chips component correctyly

See [Input multiple with tags without autoCompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635358/input-multiple-with-tags-without-autocompletion)

I'm still not sure why they created a new component. I voted against that in the PrimeFaces github and add an attribute to the existing `p:autocomplete`